# Determining an event from a date range

Tags: excel

I would like to know if it's possible in Excel to select information from a seperate column if a date is within a specified list of ranges.

I have a list of dates and another list of date ranges I want to check them against. I already know how to mark my dates with a "yes" or "no" but is it possible to pick up additional information if the result is a "yes".

For instance. Column A is my list of dates I want to check

```
A    
01/01/14
20/01/14
05/02/14
09/03/14
08/05/14
10/05/14
```

I then have a list of date ranges which relate to various events

```
B              C          D
Start data    End date   reason
24/12/13      02/01/14   Christmas
20/01/14      20/01/14   Fred Birthday
01/03/14      14/03/14   Holiday
10/05/14      10/05/14   Anniversary
```

Using the formula

```
=IF(AND(A2>=MIN(B1:C6),A2<=MAX(B1:C6)),"yes","no")
```

Can tell me for each of my dates in column A whether they fall within any of the date ranges with a yes of no, but I would like, to return the reason code from column D relating to the date match. 
So the results would look like this:

```
A            B
01/01/14     Christmas
20/01/14     Fred Birthday
05/02/14     
09/03/14     Holiday
08/05/14
10/05/14     Anniversary
```

I hope this is possible without using VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it can be done, perhaps with some auxiliary columns. I'll give it a shot. Meanwhile, your formula doesn't work. It will say "yes" for dates like 03/01/14 or 01/04/14. You are checking the date is between the minimum and the maximum of all dates, therefore, if it's between 24/12/13 and 10/05/14. I think it's worth noting that the format is DD/MM/YY.

Answer (score 0):

A very dumb way to do this will be making use of the else clause in the IF statement. The basic idea is for every field in A, check against every B and C, if matched, return D, otherwise Continue.

E.g.

```
 A             B              C          D
01/01/14    24/12/13      02/01/14   Christmas 
            20/01/14      20/01/14   Fred Birthday
            01/03/14      14/03/14   Holiday
            10/05/14      10/05/14   Anniversary

=IF(AND(A1>=B1,A1<=C1),D1,
    IF(AND(A1>=B2,A1<=C2),D2, 
      IF(AND(A1>=B3,A1<=C3),D3
         ...so on
      )
    )
  )
```

The above will return Christmas. The indentations are just for better understanding here...

Comment: The problem is when the event list grows... your IF becomes an unmaintainable monster.

Comment: Agree....thats why it's dumb. But it's good enough for the e.g. if thats the full picture of the problem.

Comment: Chaps, thanks for the suggestions thus far. Andrew, I take your point on the min/max issue. I was checking it out on a very small subset of data and I thought it was working, Alas you are right. Also, yes, the list of date ranges will be quite large in the dataset I want to run this on. I had originally thought of using nested IF statements but decided against it for this reason.

Comment: Another way might be to simply copy each field of colA n times, where n = length of event list. Then you can have one line IF statement.